# Stored procedure for advanced search

Tags: sql-server

My Table:

**CR_DETAILS**

```
CR_REF_NO VARCHAR(60), ORIGIN_ID INT, DATE_RECEIVED DATETIME, STATUS_ID INT
```

I want to develop a stored procedure to return advanced search results:

There exists search page with the fields mentioned in the above table. User can fill as many columns he is sure.

For the above table, to write stored procedure, some requirements are also there like below:
There exists a dropdownlist opposite to `DATE_RECEIVED` field with (<, >, =) options.

User enters some value against to `DATE_RECEIVED` field and he can select on of the operator. Then the search results should satisfy the condition mentioned.

Can anybody please suggest me how can I do this?

As of now, I have written the following stored procedure, but not working :(

```
ALTER PROCEDURE usp_AdvancedSearchCR
    @CR_REF_NO VARCHAR(35),
    @ORIGIN_ID INT,
    @DATE_RECEIVED DATETIME,
    @DATE_RECEIVED_COMPARE_STYLE CHAR,
    @STATUS_ID INT
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM CR_DETAILS WHERE
        ((CR_REF_NO LIKE '%' + @CR_REF_NO + '%') OR (CR_REF_NO IS NULL)) AND
        ((ORIGIN_ID = @ORIGIN_ID) OR (@ORIGIN_ID = 0)) AND
        --I am not understanding how to write code for DATE_RECEIVED
        ((STATUS_ID = @STATUS_ID) OR (@STATUS_ID = 0))
END
```

While testing the stored procedure, I have not entered any value for `DATE_RECEIVED` and tested, but I am not getting any results. Hence I understood that my other code is also wrong.

Please suggest me, it is urgent for me.

Comment: PHew - this stored proc will **not** have great performance - that's for sure!!

Comment: Please read the bible: http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html Sorry, you'll have to pick your version of SQL Server, because you didn't specify it in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write it out in the long form.  Replace your comment with the following:

```
(
 (@DATE_RECEIVED_COMPARE_STYLE = '<' AND DATE_RECEIVED < @DATE_RECEIVED) OR
 (@DATE_RECEIVED_COMPARE_STYLE = '>' AND DATE_RECEIVED > @DATE_RECEIVED) OR
 (@DATE_RECEIVED_COMPARE_STYLE = '=' AND DATE_RECEIVED = @DATE_RECEIVED)
) AND
```